# Lightswitch Search screen - choosing what you can search by

Tags: search, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a search screen which shows results from a 'projects' entity. One of the fields is a link to a 'Clients' entity, which has a client name.

I can use the search box above the data to search by project name, date, etc but I cannot search by client name. i guess because it is actually a reference to a seperate entity.

How can i make it so that I can search for projects, using the search box, by client name?

To try to explain clearer here is the database layout.

```
Project
------
ProjName
ProjType
ProjComment
Client --------------- Client
                       -----
                       Name
                       Address
```

I can search by the project fields, but not the client name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom query for Project entity and add optional parameters for all the Project and Client properties that you wish to search for. Wire up the custom query filter.
For full control do not wire up the custom query filter, instead filter in code behind, the PreProcess event.

Answer (score 1):

if your using the **HTML** **Client** it can be done as follows on a *browse* *screen* associated with in your case the Project Table. if you look at the left navigation bar, click on *edit* *query* and within here, you can see 3 options, **Filter**, **Sort** and **Parameters**.

**Filter** should say Client.Name based on your table structure, the second should be changed to "contains", the 3rd should be set as parameter and finally the 4th box is where you create the new parameter you are going to use as a search box...

you can rename the **Parameter** at the bottom and I always find its best when on this, to set it as optional in the bottom right property box. (This means all the data will be displayed rather than nothing until searched)

Now if you were to go back to your main screen page, drag this parameter from the left onto the main screen page and set it as a text box. Using this and pressing enter after you have typed something will display the results that match what you have typed so far.

a little more to the above, if you were to click "**Edit PostRender Code**" and add the below then after 3 characters are entered, the table list your searching through will be updated automatically after each finger stroke...

```
$searchBox = $("input", $(element));
setTimeout(function () {
    $searchBox.focus();
}, 1);

   onInputAsYouType(element, 1, function (text) {
    contentItem.screen.[CREATED PARAM NAME] = text; //SearchText here is the data item in the screen designer linked to the query parameter
});

function onInputAsYouType(element, numberOfRequiredChars, done) {
    var inputbox = $("input", $(element));
    inputbox.on("input", function (e) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text.length >= numberOfRequiredChars)
            done(text);
    });
};
```

};